# Hardware peripherals and device drivers windows/linux

Tags: linux, windows, drivers, peripherals, linux-device-driver

We have a query on hardware peripherals, 
How a device drivers fetch the peripheral details when it is connected to the PC for the first time. We need to know if the peripheral properties like the Device Instance Path etc. ([refer to the attached fig.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttJhp.png)) can be accessed through our custom application similar to the device driver, which will be triggered before the device driver kicks off with the installation. As we are assuming that the device driver must be reading some details to recognize the device type, it’s unique Id or service tag etc.  before kick starting when its connected for the first time.

Comment: This is very very different between Linux and Windows, so maybe restrict your question to one particular OS?

Comment: Sure, can you plz give some input on windows OS as of now,  but its really essential to know how the device starts interact with PC in Linux and windows, its appreciable even if you share some link/ docs so that we can do some more R&D on it. Thanks in advance :)